# compress dataframe to one json string apache spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that when I write it to json it has several hundred lines of json but that are exactly the same. I am trying to compress it to one json line. Is there an out of the box way to accomplish this?

```
def collect_metrics(df) -> pyspark.sql.DataFrame:
    neg_value = df.where(df.count < 0).count()

    return df.withColumn(loader_neg_values, F.lit(neg_value))

main(args):

    df_metrics = collect_metrics(df)
    df_metrics.write.json(args.metrics)
```

In the end the goal is the write one json line and the file has to be a json file, not compressed.

Comment: `df_metrics.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "snappy").json(args.metrics)`. This will compress in one line

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA thanks! But this appends "snappy"..... <filename>.json.snappy.. I think this is right direction though.

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA this does not compress it to one line. It results in a compressed snappy file but with several hundred duplicate json lines.

Comment: do you mean like `df.distinct().write...` ?

Comment: @mazaneicha not really. I just tried it still creates a json file with 100 of lines that are duplicated. I was able to just write the first row of the dataframe that would probably work.

Comment: Hmm can you show an example of your input data, more specifically the duplicated data? If calling `distinct` does not remove any lines I would expect that somehow those json lines are not exactly the same

Comment: have you tried using `toJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have hundreds of (duplicated) lines but you only want to keep one. You can use `limit(1)` in that case:

```py
df_metrics.limit(1).write.json(args.metrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
df_metrics.limit(1).repartition(1).write.json(args.metrics)
```

.repartition(1) guarantees 1 output file, and .limit(1) guarantees one output row.